# How to have Apple NetInstall and Windows Deployment Services on same subnet

Tags: wds, netinstall

I have both Windows and Apple computers on the same subnet.  I have WDS running and I need to add an OS X Mavericks with NetInstall to deploy to Apple products.  What configurations do I need to make to allow both systems to boot to their respective deployment systems?

DHCP is running on a Sonciwall TZ 210.

Comment: Split the subnet in half, and give each half a different BOOTP helper address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that *simply enabling netboot on the mac server on your one subnet and doing nothing else* isn't working (as this is often all you have to do...)

Setting netboot clients up on the same subnet as the netboot server in a 'mixed' network is in some ways trickier than setting them up on a routed network imho, as on a routed network you can just nominate the mac server as a DHCP helper on your router/layer 3 switch and this will make sure the netboot server will see the client requests.

This isn't really an issue with WDS being present on the same subnet. WDS uses some fairly simple PXE boot DHCP extensions but IIRC [the apple systems are a bit more esoteric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Service_Discovery_Protocol).

You may be able to point your clients to the netboot server with the following command in the terminal

```
sudo bless --netboot --server bsdp://ip.address.here
```

Comment: I was worried they used the same protocol and which would conflict when trying to boot the clients.  Thanks!